# how to fix error reporting in codeigniter 1.7.2 for live

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter 1.7.2 for my project, default error reporting E_ALL, at the time of upload how to fix the error reporting.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look at index.php in the root of the project. If you plan on setting it up for the production environment  (i.e. disable the error reporting) then set the environment to production.

```
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
```

You can also make changes to the error_reporting settings yourself in the same file

```
if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
        break;

        case 'testing':
        case 'production':
            error_reporting(0);
        break;
        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, may i want to replace the code instead of error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: `error_reporting(0);` disables errors

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: `error_reporting(0)` should work. Anyway since it didn't, try using `ini_set('error_reporting', 0)` in index.php. What version of PHP are you using?

BTW: you're using an extremely outdated version of CI. If it's a new project I'd advise to use v2.2.x instead.

Comment: it's an old one. i want to alter. php version in 5.4